# IOptionsBuilder<T>.Configure never hits

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm developing a web api service and some extensions for my service. I need some custom options so I'm trying to use DI mechanism. I added a named option as in bellow. But option property assingment line never hits.

```
services.AddOptions<TCustomPOCOClass>("PassLineDataTrackerOptions")
.Configure(o =>
{
  o.LocationEventInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5); // this line never hits
});
```

Comment: I'd imagine that delegate doesn't get invoked until you consume the options `services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IOptionsMonitor<TCustomPOCOClass>>().Get("PassLineDataTrackerOptions")` - not sure though

Answer (score 1):

1) `Configure` only gets called when the options are consumed.

2) Passing a name to `AddOptions` is only done is specific circumstances. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#optionsbuilder-api).

**Unnamed option example:**

```
//in Startup.cs
services.AddOptions<MyOptionsClass>()
.Configure(o =>
{
    o.Data = "test";
});

//then in the controller
public MyController(IOptionsMonitor<MyOptionsClass> optionsAccessor)
{        
    //note: Configure is called as MyController gets created by DI
    var data = optionsAccessor.CurrentValue.Data;
}
```

**Named option example:**

```
//in Startup.cs
services.AddOptions<MyOptionsClass>("optionalOptionsName")
.Configure(o =>
{
    o.Data = "test";
});

var monitor = services.BuildServiceProvider()
    .GetService<IOptionsMonitor<MyOptionsClass>>();

//note: Configure gets called on .Get
var myOptions = monitor.Get("optionalOptionsName");
```